# php SoapClient __getLastRequest() is empty

Tags: php, soap, soap-client, php-7

I'm creating `SoapClient` with `trace=1`, result is okay, but `__getLastRequest()` is empty anyway

```
$c = new \SoapClient($url, ['trace' => 1]);

$result = $sc->__soapCall('some_method_name', []);

$lr = $sc->__getLastRequest();
```

php 7.0

Answer (score 0):

```
$c = new \SoapClient($url, ['trace' => 1]);

$result = $c->__soapCall('some_method_name', []);

$lr = $c->__getLastRequest();

echo "REQUEST:\n" . $lr . "\n";
```

Just try with this....